# conditional formatting of \thesection

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, titletoc

here a not-so MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+,hyperref=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,citereset=chapter,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}


\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\label{one}
\section{First Section}
In section \ref{two} (this should be (A.1))

\mainmatter
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Second Section}
\label{two}
\ref{one} haha

\end{document}
```

In the `\tableofcontents` I want the **chapter not to appear** for the sections. 
However, if I reference something, I **want** the chapter to appear in the reference.

How can I set the `\titlecontents` using the `titletoc` package so that it doesn't display the chapterlabel?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\p@section`, the prefix that's used for cross references, but not when generating the counter's representation:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly in the MWE I provided, however not in the PhD thesis I'm writing. What in hell is causing it, no idea. So I want to use titletoc now to do this. I updated the question.